# Ionic Pro error missing binding

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework

Currently I have built an ionic app and when testing it locally everything works.  I run ionic build and there are no errors.
I then upload my ionic app to ionic pro dashboard via this way:
1. I link the account 
2. I "git push ionic master"

The upload works and then I get an error in the dashboard the error is "Build error".  The error on the log is this:

```
Error: Missing binding /usr/src/app/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-57/binding.node
Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment: Linux 64-bit with Node.js 8.x

Found bindings for the following environments:
  - OS X 64-bit with Node.js 8.x
```

If I was running this locally and received this error it can be resolved by running 'nom rebuild node-sass --force'.  However since I don't have access to run any commands on the ionic dashboard I can't fix it.  I have tried the following this.

1. I created a new app and upload everything with out any node modules or the package lock json file.
2. I found the missing linux binding node it is requiring and placed it in the appropriate director and pushed everything (including node modules).

Neither was the fix.  Does anyone have any ideas how this can be resolved?

Answer (score 1):

Just run this and it will reinstall the bindings for your new environment, good luck!!

```
sudo npm rebuild node-sass
```